# How to remove double first quote from the line in shell script

Tags: shell

```
Line1 : "TF_TOKEN"="test2"

Line2: "TF_TEST_TOKEN"="test3"

Expected output:  

1: TF_TOKEN="test2"

2: TF_TEST_TOKEN="test3"
```

Thanks

How to remove the double first quote from the line

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove the first two instances of a double quote, or all instances of a double quote that precede `=`?  What do you want to do with `"unmatched="foo"` or `"embe\"dded"="true"`?

Comment: i want to remove the first two instances of a double quote. remain the double quotes after equal to
Output should be like TF_TOKEN="test2"

,Remove double quotes from TF_TOKEN and remain "test2"

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to remove the first two instances of `"`, you can remove the first instance twice:

```
$ cat input
Line1 : "TF_TOKEN"="test2"
Line2: "TF_TEST_TOKEN"="test3"
$ sed -e 's/"//1' -e 's/"//1' input
Line1 : TF_TOKEN="test2"
Line2: TF_TEST_TOKEN="test3"
```

But more likely you are looking for something like:

```
sed -e 's/"\([^="]*\)"/\1/'
```